# Can i run a vert.x instance inside an application server like tomcat or jboss

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, websocket, vert.x

I'm a newbie in Websockets and i would like to know if it's possible to run a Websocket server from a Servlet for example, if answer is no, please give me an explanation.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Of course you can. But what are you expecting or hoping for? I think the easiest way would be to listen on a different port. In other words, handling or overriding the Tomcat plumbing would take more work. https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/embed

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Here is an example of how to embed vert.x in a grails app, which can be run inside Tomcat, https://gist.github.com/pledbrook/2652835.

Comment: you mean i can write :
PlatformManager pm = PlatformLocator.factory.createPlatformManager();
inside a servlet ?
I use java so i don't really understand you sample...

Comment: I think so, although I have never tried it in Java. Also, you can find an example about "Embedding Vert.x core" in the vertx doc you mentioned. That example showed how to create a TCP server with an embeded Vert.x.

BTW, if your purpose is only to create a websocket server and don't want to use other features in vertx. You can try [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) too.